# Accelerated Wallis' product

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Recently I have obtained the following:

$$ \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}
  \left(1 + \frac 1{4\cdot k^2\cdot(4\cdot k-3)}\right)\,\
 =\,\ \frac 4\pi $$
or, equivalently,
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{\infty}
  \left(1 - \frac 1{(2\cdot k-1)^2\cdot(4\cdot k+1))}\right)\,\
 =\,\ \frac \pi 4 $$

where I have used the Wallis product. (These equations sound so classical that they must be well-known; I'd appreciate a reference.)

**QUESTION**   Do you know or can you provide simple proofs of the above equation which do not use the Wallis product?

**REMARK 1**   Perhaps different proofs of Wallis theorem may lead to different proofs of the above formulas (e.g. via Fourier analysis?).

**REMARK 2**   In general, products $\ \prod_{k=1}^n (1+a_k)\ $ (where $\ a_k\ $ are small) can be treated by the Euler's method by studying $\ \sum_{k=1}^n\log(a_k),\ $ etc.

Comment: This question got downvoted a couple days ago or so. I am curious what would be the reason?

Answer (score 4):

Let's consider the partial product $P_n:=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(4k+1)(2k-1)^2}{(2k)^2(4k-3)}$. Then, convert to factorials:
\begin{align} P_n&=\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{4k+1}{4k-3}\cdot\prod_{k=1}^n\frac{(2k)^2(2k-1)^2}{(2k)^4} \\
&=\frac{4n+1}{2^{4n}}\binom{2n}n^2=(4n+1)\left(\frac{(2n)!}{2^{2n}n!^2}\right)^2.
\end{align}
Applying [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) $n!\sim \sqrt{2\pi n}\,\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n$, we find that
\begin{align} P_n \,\,&\sim\,\, (4n+1)\left(\frac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\,\left(\frac{2n}e\right)^{2n}}{2^{2n}(2\pi n)\,\left(\frac{n}e\right)^{2n}} \right)^2 \\
&=\frac{4n+1}{\pi n} \\
&\rightarrow \frac4{\pi},
\end{align}
as $n\rightarrow\infty$. The proof follows. Note: this does not accelerate the product any more than the Wallis formula does.

If you like to know a bit more about this and related topics, you may look into this paper:

> Tewodros Amdeberhan, Olivier R. Espinosa, Victor H. Moll, Armin Straub, *Wallis–Ramanujan–Schur–Feynman*, American Mathematical Monthly **117** (2010) pp 618–632, doi:[10.4169/000298910X496741](https://doi.org/10.4169/000298910X496741) , arXiv:[1004.2453](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2453) ([pdf](http://dauns.math.tulane.edu/~vhm/papers_html/wrsf.pdf))

Comment: T.A., thank you for your answer. Using Stirling's approximation seems less elementary than using Wallis product--in fact, a popular way to obtain the Stirling's theorem (the version which you use) is by applying the Wallis product, then it's simple. *** Thank you for your link too, I'll have a look.

Comment: Nice title of that paper, by the way!

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thank you!